# UIView (with UIButton) on top of a UIView - how to activate button programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I have a `UIVIew` with Button. This is loaded in the `VIewController` as hidden. No problem unhiding it but the button on top of it is not working. Is the `UIview` class the right place to put the codes for the exit button (hiding it again)?

in **.h**

```
@interface infoView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *infoTextView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *exitButton;

-(void)exitView:(UIButton*)sender;

@end
```

in **.m**

```
#import "infoView.h"

@implementation infoView

@synthesize infoTextView = _infoTextView;
@synthesize exitButton=_exitButton;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
        _infoTextView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 240, 240)];
        [_infoTextView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor blueColor]];
        [self addSubview:_infoTextView];

        _exitButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 10, 30, 30)];
        //other info
        [self.infoTextView addSubview:self.exitButton];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)exitView:(UIButton*)sender
{
    self.infoTextView.hidden=YES;
}
```

viewController

```
@implementation gjViewController


@synthesize imageViewMain = _imageViewMain;
@synthesize changeImageButton = _changeImageButton;
@synthesize infoButton = _infoButton;
@synthesize myInfo = _myInfo;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


_imageViewMain = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
//other info
[self.view addSubview:self.imageViewMain];

_changeImageButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 50, 100, 50)];
 //other info
[self.view addSubview:self.changeImageButton];

_infoButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260, 30, 40, 40)];
//other details
[self.view addSubview: self.infoButton];
```

the section below is the part where the UIView is loaded. It loads and unhides with the IBAction at the bottom. I think you are pointing that this is wrong, not sure how. Thanks for comments.

```
_myInfo = [[infoView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:_myInfo];
[_myInfo setHidden:YES];

}

-(IBAction)newImage:(UIButton*)sender{
  //task

-(IBAction)oldImage:(UIButton*)sender{
  //taks

-(IBAction)viewInfo:(UIButton*)sender{     <--- unhides the UIView
[_myInfo setHidden:NO];
```

Comment: Your button needs to be above your view in the hierarchy if you are using a storyboard.

Comment: Where is ImageView mentioned in title?

Comment: If this is an image view you might need to enable user interaction on it.

Comment: The question is not clear... Maybe author wants to say that button doesn't receive touch when its parent view becomes hidden?

Comment: (1) Do I need to make an instance of every item in an instance? e.g. button in the UIview? (2) sorry changes made - UIVIew. (3) Button does not receive touch when viewed.